# Aligning function arguments in "algorithm" environment.

Tags: listings, horizontal-alignment, algorithms

In the "algorithm" environment, when a function call spans multiple lines, I would like to have its arguments aligned, like so:

```
MyFunction(long_arg_name0,
           long_arg_name1,
           long_arg_name2);
```

How can I achieve this effect?

**(second) EDIT**: Here's a minimal example that fails to achieve the desired effect:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\begin{algorithmic}
  \While{true}
  \State MyLongWindedFunction(LongArgument0,\\ LongArgument1,\\ LongArgument2,\\ LongArgument3)
  \EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

When I stick the standard alignment marker `&` between the arguments, I get the error message:

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.10   \State MyLongWindedFunction(LongArgument0,&
                                               \\ LongArgument1, &\\ Lon...
```

Comment: Please post a complete, minimal and compilable (including the document class, the relevant packages used) version of your code.

Comment: Ok, compilable example added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to calculate the length of the string that preceeds the alignment point (in this case, the string `MyLongWindedFunction(` ) and then use this length to add the necessary horizontal space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{MyLongWindedFunction(}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\begin{algorithmic}
  \State MyLongWindedFunction(LongArgument0,\\\hspace{\mylen}LongArgument1,\\\hspace{\mylen}LongArgument2,\\\hspace{\mylen}LongArgument3)
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

To answer the EDIT in the original question: simply add `\parindent` (the indentation used in the algorithm) to the length `\mylen`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{MyLongWindedFunction(}
\addtolength\mylen{\parindent}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\begin{algorithmic}
  \While{true}
  \State MyLongWindedFunction(LongArgument0,\\\hspace*{\mylen}LongArgument1,\\\hspace*{\mylen}LongArgument2,\\\hspace*{\mylen}LongArgument3)
  \EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just discovered that this solution doesn't quite work when MyLongWindedFunction is within a loop block, since the function itself is indented a few spaces away from the left, a spacing not captured by \settowidth\mylen{MyLongWindedFunction(}. I've changed the example code above to include such a loop. Any workaround ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @SuperElectric: I added some code showing you how to proceed; all you have to do is to add the length of `\parindent` to `\mylen.`